# class imagine/gd/imagine not found in yii2

Tags: yii2

Class 'Imagine\Gd\Imagine' not found

I am using cropbox extension in yii2 and it is throughing this error 
although namespace yii/imagine is used in model file

Following is model class file

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\imagine;
use yii\imagine\Image;
// use yii\imagine\Gd;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Image\Point;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "tbl_slider_pics".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $path
 * @property integer $status
 * @property string $ip
 * @property string $crt_by
 * @property string $crt_time
 * @property string $mod_by
 * @property string $mod_time
 */
class TblSliderPics extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
     public $image;
    public $crop_info;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_slider_pics';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['path'], 'required'],
            [['status'], 'integer'],
            [['path'], 'string', 'max' => 2000],
            [['ip'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['crt_by', 'mod_by'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['crt_time', 'mod_time'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
[
        'image', 
        'image', 
        'extensions' => ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
        'mimeTypes' => ['image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'],
    ],
    ['crop_info', 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'path' => 'Path',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'ip' => 'Ip',
            'crt_by' => 'Crt By',
            'crt_time' => 'Crt Time',
            'mod_by' => 'Mod By',
            'mod_time' => 'Mod Time',
        ];
    }

public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
   // open image
    $image = Image::getImagine()->open($this->image->tempName);

    // rendering information about crop of ONE option 
    $cropInfo = Json::decode($this->crop_info)[0];
    $cropInfo['dWidth'] = (int)$cropInfo['dWidth']; //new width image
    $cropInfo['dHeight'] = (int)$cropInfo['dHeight']; //new height image
    $cropInfo['x'] = $cropInfo['x']; //begin position of frame crop by X
    $cropInfo['y'] = $cropInfo['y']; //begin position of frame crop by Y
    // Properties bolow we don't use in this example
    //$cropInfo['ratio'] = $cropInfo['ratio'] == 0 ? 1.0 : (float)$cropInfo['ratio']; //ratio image. 
    //$cropInfo['width'] = (int)$cropInfo['width']; //width of cropped image
    //$cropInfo['height'] = (int)$cropInfo['height']; //height of cropped image
    //$cropInfo['sWidth'] = (int)$cropInfo['sWidth']; //width of source image
    //$cropInfo['sHeight'] = (int)$cropInfo['sHeight']; //height of source image

    //delete old images
    $oldImages = FileHelper::findFiles(Yii::getAlias('/home/sweet947/public_html/fortaj.ca/backend/uploads/'), [
        'only' => [
            $this->id . '.*',
            'thumb_' . $this->id . '.*',
        ], 
    ]);
    for ($i = 0; $i != count($oldImages); $i++) {
        @unlink($oldImages[$i]);
    }

    //saving thumbnail
    $newSizeThumb = new Box($cropInfo['dWidth'], $cropInfo['dHeight']);
    $cropSizeThumb = new Box(200, 200); //frame size of crop
    $cropPointThumb = new Point($cropInfo['x'], $cropInfo['y']);
    $pathThumbImage = Yii::getAlias('/home/sweet947/public_html/fortaj.ca/backend/uploads/') 
        . '/thumb_' 
        . $this->id 
        . '.' 
        . $this->image->getExtension();  

    $image->resize($newSizeThumb)
        ->crop($cropPointThumb, $cropSizeThumb)
        ->save($pathThumbImage, ['quality' => 100]);

    //saving original
    $this->path->saveAs(
        Yii::getAlias('/home/sweet947/public_html/fortaj.ca/backend/uploads/') 
        . '/' 
        . $this->id 
        . '.' 
        . $this->image->getExtension()
    );
}
}
```

Please help me!!

Comment: namespace problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190053/class-imagine-gd-imagine-not-found-in-yii2/33190125 .. remember you must add the "use....."  where you use the code

Comment: do i have to add it in controller too?

Comment: PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'Imagine\Gd\Imagine' not found

Comment: Have you added this extension in your config file?